# Express equality constraint involving exponentials cones

Tags: convex-optimization, disciplined-convex-programming, cone

The exponential cone is define such that
$(x, y, z) \in \text{ExpCone: if }  y \exp(x / y) \leq z \land y > 0.$ The inequality $\exp(a) \leq b$ can be expressed as $[a, 1, b] \in \text{ExpCone}$.

How do i write $\exp(a) = b$ using cone programming?

Comment: $y = 0$ is also possible -- you need to take the closure of this definition.

Comment: $y = 0$ is not possible in my definition includes $y > 0$ after an logic and ($\land$).

Comment: That's my point! $y=0$ must be included in the definition of Exponential Cone. The current definition is incomplete, and to complete it you must take the closure of the set of points that satisfy what you have written.

Comment: @independentvariable There are numerous sources with $y > 0$. I haven't seen any with $y \ge 0$.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/expo.html

Comment: @independentvariable Yes, that is one of my sources.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Which defines it with the possibility of $y = 0$. So I really think one should include the limits of the set that is defined above in the question.

Comment: O.k., I concede the point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Q**: "How do i write $\text{exp}(a) = b$ using cone programming?"

**A** You don't.

$\text{exp}(a) = b$ is a nonlinear equality constraint, and is therefore non-convex.

$\text{exp}(a) \le b$ is convex. But to produce $\text{exp}(a) = b$, it would need to be paired with $\text{exp}(a) \ge b$, which is going in the wrong direction to be convex.

Comment: Me being the devil's advocate: $x^{2} = 0$ is a nonlinear equality constraint, and it is convex (as in, it defines a convex set). That's a horrible way of writing $x=0$, but it's convex nonetheless :)

Comment: @mtannea Yes, I have used that example myself. (if not on this forum, then on some optimization software forum) But I decided not to be pedantic this time. Actually, one way of looking at $x^2 = 0$ is as $x^2 \le 0$, which is convex, with the other direction, $ x^2 \ge 0$ not being needed (which is similar to how complementarity constraint is changed from $.... = 0$ to$ ... \le 0$ for feeding to SQP solver).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the SQP part. Thanks!

Comment: @mtanneua See for example, R. Fletcher, S. Leyffer, D. Ralph, and S. Scholtes. "Local convergence of SQP methods for mathematical programs with equilibrium constraints". SIAM Journal Optimization, 17(1):259–286, 2006.  https://www.mcs.anl.gov/~leyffer/papers/MPEC-SQP-15.pdf . There also some more recent publications.